# The annihilator induces a module

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring, and $M$ an $R$-leftmodule. Let $\operatorname{Ann}_R(M)$ be the annihilator of M, meaning that $r m = 0 \space\space\space\space  \forall r \in \operatorname{Ann}_R(M), m \in M$.

Let $I \subseteq \operatorname{Ann}_R(M)$ be a two-sided ideal. Show that M is naturally an $R/I$-module.

Thanks in advance! I'm not that used to annihilators, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prove that if $r\equiv s \mod I$, then $rm=sm$ for any $m\in $M$.

That is equivalent to $(r-s)m=0$, which is by definition since $r\equiv s\mod I\iff r-s\in I\subseteq\operatorname{Ann}_AM$.